# При ошибке выдает 500статус, как сделать чтобы просто показывало пустую страницу?

Tags: php, http-status-code-500

не хочу чтобы пользователи видели ошибки сайта, чтобы они писались в лог файл. Но если я выключаю показ ошибок пользователям - мне сервер выдает - ошибка 500.

```
ini_set("display_startup_errors","0");
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

А если включаю вывод пользователю ошибок - показывает ошибку.

Пробовал через .htaccess указать страницу при ошибке 500, но все-равно показывает "Страница недоступна" HTTP ERROR 500

```
ErrorDocument 500 500.php




ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если есть ошибка, то пользователю не показывало текст ошибки, а просто пустую страницу, и не отдавало ошибку 500?

Comment: добавь слеш к 500.зрз

Answer (score 1):

Это глупо.
Пустая страница еще хуже ошибки. Это будет раздражать пользователей.

Надо быть честным со своими посетителями. Ну или немножечко приврать, как это делает, например, Stack Overflow - при ошибках он пишет, что проходит "Плановая профилактика сайта". Но в любом случае надо написать что-то осмысленное, а не заставлять пользователя теряться в непонятках.

поэтому ты совершенно правильно решил использовать директиву ErrorDocument, но только надо передавать в нее имя существующего файла и писать к нему полный путь от корня сайта.

Comment: Так и сделал, файл 500.php лежит в корне сайта. Пустую страницу - для примера написал

Comment: надо писать /500.php если лежит в корне. Плюс посмотри какой конкретно код ошибки выдает РНР. открой эту страницу в консоли браузера, владка Сеть и посмотри НТТР код ответа. возможно это 502 или 503

Comment: Сделал со слешем, в консоле статус 500. Пишу в тех. поддержку, может подскажут

Comment: еще надо убедиться, что на сайте используется веб-сервер Апач

Comment: В заголовках пишет что сервер nginx

Comment: Хотя при ошибке 404 пишет Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) Server

Answer (score 1):

Поддержка хостинга дала ответ, что для ошибок 5хх не работает директива 
ErrorDocument

Согласно документации.

https://serverfault.com/questions/675307/apache-not-displaying-custom-500-error-page-for-php-errors

Comment: В ответе на  serverfault написан бред.

Comment: @Ипатьев тем не менее, ошибки статусов 4хх - работают, а 5хх - нет...

Comment: а какая версия РНР?

Comment: @Ипатьев 5.6 версия